# Unable to save lists to MongoDB using UpdateDefinitionBuilder in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the following helper function that uses reflection to look at the supplied model, check if any fields are non-null, and overwrite those with new values in MongoDB.

It works fine until I try updating a `List<string>` field. Instead of saving the list as an array to MongoDB, it saves a string value of **"(Collection)"** in MongoDB. What am I missing to make this work?

I don't want to hardcode that any `List` should default to `List<string>` either. It's possible I could have lists of ints.

```
    public override MyObj Update(MyObj model)
    {
        var builder = Builders<MyObj>.Update;
        var builder_def = builder.Set(x => x.Id, model.Id);

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in model.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            var value = model.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(model, null);

            if (value != null)
            {
                builder_def = builder_def.Set(prop.Name, value); // Not setting lists correctly
            }
        }

        var filter = Builders<MyObj>.Filter;
        var filter_def = filter.Eq(x => x.Id, model.Id);

        Connection.Update(filter_def, builder_def);

        return model;
    }
```

**Edit**

I think my problem is related to this open bug https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1984. Given that, is there any way for me to make this work in that context?